# Get unmatched rows from two tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables table_a and table_b. The table structures looks like:

**table_a:**

```
col_name  |  data_type                        
----------+--------------
  name    |   nvarchar
  age     |   nvarchar
  city    |   nvarchar
  dob     |   nvarchar
```

**table_b:**

```
col_name  |  data_type                        
----------+--------------
  name    |   nvarchar
  age     |   int
  city    |   nvarchar
  dob     |   datetime
 country  |   nvarchar
```

Now, I want all those column names which has unmatched data_type i.e. age and dob in output result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hmmm . . . assuming the tables are in the same database, you can use `information_schema`:

```
select c.column_name
from information_schema.columns c
where c.table_name in ('table_a', 'table_b')
group by c.column_name
having min(data_type) <> max(data_type)
```

Note:  This does not return columns that are only in one table.  If you wanted that, add `or count(*) = 1`.